# Passing javax.mail.Message on a stream

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am using the JavaMail API to get some emails. I would like to get a Stream of the Messages and then on the other side get the Stream back to a email. Also I don't want to lose any properties like attachments, destination, sender, body, etc....

How can accomplish this?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I was thinking about using the getInputStream... but then I realized that I was incomplete.... I was losing the header and stuff... also I couldn't get back to a Message object

Comment: You mean you want to send those messages to another server besides the one that is getting them from the mail server?

Comment: No. I am working on a app that has 3 main components, datasources, inputmodules and output modules. I am using Streams to pass everything from the data source to the modules. So I want to reduce the mail objects (Message I believe) to a Stream, so I can receive it on the IOModules and handlee it as I want to the business logic. but to do so it would be nice to have a way to pass from Message to Stream and then Stream to Message.
Also I don't know if I am using the correct object type (referring to the javax.mail.Message). Is there a more suitable way to do this

Comment: I don't understand why I received a down vote since this question is not bad... shame...3

Answer (score 2):

Ok... I managed to find out the answer how this can be accomplished

we can use the

.writeTo( out );

to write into a OutputStream, send it a InputStream and finally you can reconstruct it using this

Message receivedMail = new MimeMessage( session, inputStream );

problem fixed!

Answer (score 1):

Please check the sample code below:

```
  URLName url = new URLName("pop3","xxxx",123,"","user","password");
  Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
  Store store = new POP3SSLStore(session,url);
  store.connect();

  Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
  folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

  Message message[] = folder.getMessages(); 

  for (int i=0; i <message.length;i++) {
      Message message = messages[i];

      //Get Message Properties
      System.out.println("From : " + message.getFrom()[0]);
      System.out.println("Subject : " + message.getSubject());
      System.out.println("Sent Date : " + message.getSentDate());

      //Get Input stream for each message
      InputStream is = message.getInputStream();
      .....
      is.close();
  }
  folder.close(false);
  store.close();
```

To construct the message backwards:

```
      MimeMessage newMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
      MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = new MimeMultipart();
      MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart(is);
      attachment.setHeader("Content-Type", "contentType");
      mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(attachment);
      newMessage.setContent(mimeMultipart);
      newMessage.setFrom(InternetAddress.parse("fromAddress")[0]);
      newMessage.setReplyTo(InternetAddress.parse("toAddress"));
      newMessage.setSubject("subject");
```

Comment: I believe that it doesn't do the trick, That is the code I have done already... How do you pass from the inputstream back to message?

Comment: @Killercode: Please note, I used few attributes only from original message. You may want to include more.

Comment: Strange... when I construct the message back again... it does not create it... no even the body text... :(

Comment: @Killercode I think you need to set some more attributes such as `DataHandler`.